# How did Yahshua/Jesus observe the Sabbath?

Tags: jesus, law, torah, sabbath

Peace, Blessings, and Divine Love. Being how Christ was ethnically a Hebrew, being an Israelite from the tribe of Judah, he observed the teachings/laws of Moses.  Numerous times he was able to highlight and point out the hypocrisies of how the Pharisees, Sadducees, and other religious authorities in his time misapplied/failed in their execution of the very same Torah/Mishna/Law they proclaimed to be adherent to.  One of the most famous encounters is [Matthew 12:1-8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew%2012%3A1-8&version=KJV):

> 1 At that time Jesus went on the sabbath day through the corn; and
> his disciples were an hungred, and began to pluck the ears of corn and
> to eat.
>
> 2 But when the Pharisees saw it, they said unto him, Behold, thy
> disciples do that which is not lawful to do upon the sabbath day.
>
> 3 But he said unto them, Have ye not read what David did, when he was
> an hungred, and they that were with him;
>
> 4 How he entered into the house of God, and did eat the shewbread,
> which was not lawful for him to eat, neither for them which were with
> him, but only for the priests?
>
> 5 Or have ye not read in the law, how that on the sabbath days the
> priests in the temple profane the sabbath, and are blameless?
>
> 6 But I say unto you, That in this place is one greater than the
> temple.
>
> 7 But if ye had known what this meaneth, I will have mercy, and not
> sacrifice, ye would not have condemned the guiltless.
>
> 8 For the Son of man is Lord even of the sabbath day.

To me, this highlighted once again how the Pharisees, missed the mark ([Sin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_views_on_sin#Transgression)).  From the commandment given in [Exodus 20:8-11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2020%3A8-11&version=KJV), [Deuteronomy 5:12-14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%205%3A12-14&version=KJV), and [Isaiah 58:13-14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isaiah%2058%3A13-14&version=KJV), how exactly did Yahshua/Jesus/Christ observe/respect the sabbath?

As always biblical scriptures (non-biblical scriptures are welcomed as well), articles, personal insights/thoughts, etc are welcomed. Thank you.

([For what it's worth I came across this question as well on the Christian StackExchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/75771/51919)).

Comment: This reads like a theological synthesis question. Please [edit] it to more clearly ask an exegetical question about a single passage.

Comment: @curiousdannii Peace, may you please elaborate? The singular passage is Matthew 12 (how Christ highlighted and shot down the Pharisee's unrighteous judgement pertaining to the Shabbat).  I brought out the other scriptures showing that Christ had/was observing the Shabbat all leading to me asking how though?  It was the same law for everyone but he did it correctly.  The New Testament does not explicitly give a breakdown on how he observed the day but showed instances and examples of when he was accused of not and his rebuttal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several incidents in the NT that help to understand how Jesus kept the Sabbath day "holy" (Gen 2:1-3).

- Jesus encouraged good (charitable) deeds on the Sabbath.  Matt 12:11, 12.

> He replied, “If one of you has a sheep and it falls into a pit on the
> Sabbath, will he not take hold of it and lift it out? How much more
> valuable is a man than a sheep! Therefore it is lawful to do good on
> the Sabbath.”

See also Mark 3:4, Luke 6:9.

- Thus, the Sabbath was an occasion for Jesus to heal (including miracles) and to do good, Mark 1:21-28, 29-31, 3:1-6, Luke 13:10-17, 14:1-6, John 5:1-18, 13:10-17.
- Jesus attended Synagogue for fellowship and learning from the Scriptures Luke 4:16.

> Then Jesus came to Nazareth, where He had been brought up. As was His
> custom, He entered the synagogue on the Sabbath. And when He stood up
> to read

In summary, Jesus kept the Sabbath as it was intended - as a day for celebrating and enjoying (Isa 58:13, 14) our Creator and Recreator (Ex 31:12-17) without the accumulated silly rules created by men.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and beautiful response.  I had questions about how far one is able to do good deeds and how far is the line where one is going from truly keeping it in its original intent, to as you mentioned making it "common".

Comment: Dottard, You said **silly rules created by man**. Are you referring to this based on what the Greek text says about the Pharisees making the law burdensome or are you referring to the oral Thora and what is given as the 613 laws in the Talmud? I ask as I wish you understand why the greek testament talks so negatively about the law. Please can we dialogue on this point?

Comment: @YedduPrasad - "silly rules" is a broad term used for any rule about the Sabbath not found in the Bible, from whatever source - and there are lots of them.

Comment: Dottard, There are 613 laws. G-d gave to Moses as in Thorah.  Shabbat has 5 laws 1. To rest on the seventh day (Exodus 23:12), 2. Not to do prohibited labor on the seventh day(Exodus 20:10), 3. The court must not inflict punishment on Shabbat(Exodus 35:3), 4 Not to walk outside the city boundary on Shabbat(Exodus 16:29), 5. To sanctify the day with Kiddush and Havdallah (Exodus 20:8) Now let me ask you for #2 what is prohibited and what is not? I am sure you will have a view and I will have my view. Oral law(Talmud) helps define it. Why Greek text used this as offensive I fail to understand?

Comment: Dottard, Also Hebrew letter does not have vowels so when people read the scrolls, they had to remember what prepositions, conjunctions, adjectives, etc.. need to go there. Imagine an issue where each person added what he thought was right and it would be a mess. Oral law helps here as well. Also, these were decided by commoners. They were done by sages and passed on from generation to generation. God Bless.

Comment: I am sure you have read each of the 613 laws. is G-d is asking too much? Is G-d asking something that we cannot keep? In all likelihood, we are keeping most of the laws. Why does Paul teach just the opposite? Between G-d and Paul I will choose G-d. God Bless. https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/the-613-mitzvot-commandments